# Retrieving all genders by default in dotnet core 2.1

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have an application that I am trying to filter by gender. I have a class that I store gender as below:

```
public class SampleParams
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    ...

}
```

In my repository class, I query the result as below:

```
var samples = context.Samples.AsQueryable();
samples = samples.Where(u => u.Gender == sampleParams.Gender);
```

And in my controller class, I check to make sure my `SampleParams` class has value as below:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleParams.Gender))
{
    sampleParams.Gender = sampleParams.Gender == "female" ? "male" : "female";
}

var samples = await repository.GetAllSamples(sampleParams);
...
```

In the SQL server, I have "male", "female" and null values in the Gender field. The problem that I have is that when I test this with PostMan, I get only female because I set the `sample.Params` to "female" by default. I am trying to retrieve samples with all genders (along with null) if the `sampleParams.Gender" is null by default. 
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: `sampleParams.Gender == "female" ? "male" : "female"`this doesn't seem right, do you want to switch gender?

Comment: The code above gives me female by default if I don't select any value. If I select male, it returns male. My goal is to retrieve all gender (with nulls) if I don't select anything. I am not sure if I explained it well.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you, `sampleParams.Gender = sampleParams.Gender == "female" ? "male" : "female"` changes the value of `sampleParams.Gender`, if it's female, it becomes male, otherwise (including null), it becomes female

Comment: Let e me try to explain from this way: what should I do the following query if  want to display all genders with null? `sampleParams.Gender = sampleParams.Gender == "female" ? "male" : "female";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore the gender filter in case it's null:

```
var samples = context.Samples.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleParams.Gender))
{
    samples = samples.Where(u => u.Gender == sampleParams.Gender);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete this:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleParams.Gender))
 {
    sampleParams.Gender = sampleParams.Gender == "female" ? "male" : "female";
 }
```

And in your repository class do this:

```
var samples = context.Samples.AsQueryable();
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleParams.Gender)?samples:samples.Where(u => u.Gender == sampleParams.Gender);
```

Hopes it help. Greetings